Checking that an inequality holds
I have ended up with a slightly complicated inequality
\begin{equation}
 -(n - q + y)^2 - 4 n q + q (n + q - y) + (n + y)\sqrt{(n - q + y)^2 + 4 n q} > 0
\end{equation}
I believe that this inequality is true assuming that $y > 0$, $n > 0$ and $q > 0$. However, I am not sure how to show this; does anyone have any suggestions?
Some attempts
One idea is minimise the expression with respect to the variables (to get a lower bound). Indeed, it seems that the function attains a minimum of $0$ when $n, y, q$ are constrained to be non-negative. However, I feel like there must be a better way to do this! [Doing the minimisation also complexifies the argument since the variables are meant to be positive, not non-negative.]
Another idea (suggested by @RiverLi) is to rewrite the inequality like so
\begin{equation}
q (n + q - y) + (n + y)\sqrt{(n - q + y)^2 + 4 n q} >  (n - q + y)^2 + 4 n q 
\end{equation}
Here, it is tempting to square both sides -- but can we be sure that the LHS is positive? After all, $y$ could exceed $n + q$, so the first term could be negative. Of course, the LHS is positive if the statement is true (using the positivity of the RHS); but the truth of the inequality is in question! In any case, squaring both sides does not seem to easily resolve the problem.

Mathematica has its own stackexchange. Reduce has an Assumptions option, check the documentation for Reduce and Assumptions: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html. You can also try Refine with Assuming, see the documentation for Assuming: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html

@RandyMarsh yes I know that thanks; however, this question is not really about Mathematica. (Ideally, I would solve it without using Mathematica at all!)

@afreelunch Simply rearrange the terms and square both sides.

@RiverLi Many thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry if I am being slow but I can't quite see how to make this work -- can you help me out? I have edited the question to make the issue clearer.

@afreelunch $ (n + y)\sqrt{(n - q + y)^2 + 4 n q} > -[-(n - q + y)^2 - 4 n q + q (n + q - y) ]$, then square both sides.

Thanks! I think this then simplifies to $n q^2 y > 0$, which is true.
